# partial Distance Based RDA - Centroids vanished from Plot

Tags: vegan, rda

I am trying to fir a partial db-RDA with field.ID to correct for the repeated measurements character of the samples. However including Condition(field.ID) leads to Disappearance of the centroids of the main factor of interest from the plot (left plot below).

The Design: 12 fields have been sampled for species data in two consecutive years, repeatedly. Additionally every year 3 samples from reference fields have been sampled. These three fields have been changed in the second year, due to unavailability of the former fields.
Additionally some environmental variables have been sampled (Nitrogen, Soil moisture, Temperature). Every field has an identifier (field.ID).
Using field.ID as Condition seem to erroneously remove the F1 factor. However using Sampling campaign (SC) as Condition does not. Is the latter the rigth way to correct for repeated measurments in partial db-RDA??

set.seed(1234)

```
df.exp <- data.frame(field.ID = factor(c(1:12,13,14,15,1:12,16,17,18)),
                     SC = factor(rep(c(1,2), each=15)),
                     F1 = factor(rep(rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),each=3),2)),
                     Nitrogen  = rnorm(30,mean=0.16, sd=0.07),
                     Temp  = rnorm(30,mean=13.5, sd=3.9),
                     Moist  = rnorm(30,mean=19.4, sd=5.8))

df.rsp <- data.frame(Spec1 = rpois(30, 5),
                     Spec2 = rpois(30,1),
                     Spec3 = rpois(30,4.5),
                     Spec4 = rpois(30,3),
                     Spec5 = rpois(30,7),
                     Spec6 = rpois(30,7),
                     Spec7 = rpois(30,5))

data=cbind(df.exp, df.rsp)                  



dbRDA <- capscale(df.rsp ~ F1 + Nitrogen + Temp + Moist + Condition(SC), df.exp); ordiplot(dbRDA)
dbRDA <- capscale(df.rsp ~ F1 + Nitrogen + Temp + Moist + Condition(field.ID), df.exp); ordiplot(dbRDA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You partial out variation due to `ID` and then you try to explain variable aliased to this `ID`, but it was already partialled out. The key line in the printed output was this:

```
Some constraints were aliased because they were collinear (redundant)
```

And indeed, when you ask for details, you get

```
> alias(dbRDA, names=TRUE)
[1] "F1B" "F1C" "F1D" "F1E"
```

The `F1?` variables were constant within  `ID` which already was partialled out, and nothing was left to explain.

Comment: @ Jari Oksanen Thanks for answering! I hoped this would work in the same way as mixed effects models. I suspected sth. similar, however I would have said, ID is nested within Factor1...?! That would not be the case, if all IDs  appeared in all levels of the factor, right? However, I regard the latter to be uncommon in field ecological studies with repeated measurements. Must I take the average for ID before running rda, if I have repeated measurements, then?